# How to find out your own English level?

Tags: english

I want to find out my English level (A1-C2). I thought it will be a good idea to find some placement tests. 
Where I can find some free, good English placement tests with some feedback?

Comment: Questions about tests used to be on topic, I think. This question would be improved by slightly more focus than "English level" - vocabulary, grammar, speech, understanding, etc.?

Comment: @AML Closed on ELL: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/176069/49182

Comment: @AML Please don't send people to other sites if the question is relevant or can be made relevant to our site. We have had a similar question, with a focus on Polish, in the past: [How to certify language skills online](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2501/800).

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question a bit. Strictly speaking, a placement test is a test offered by a language school to determine what level of course you should attend at their school. Could you please say whether the "level" refers to [CEFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages) or something else?

Comment: Simple question, so many answers, but everything is off-topic. The placement test are tests which are showing you a level of your language competencies, not only at the language schools, but at universities too. So many people have lost their time to prove that my question is not appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are 10 different options to help you find out your English level:

- [15 questions - Language Levels](https://www.languagelevel.com/english/index.php)
- [83 questions - Cambridge Institute](http://quizlevel.cambridgeinstitute.net/index.php/en/en-test-ingles)
- [Cambridge Assessment placement test (must register)](https://www.cambridgeenglish.org/find-a-centre/exam-centres/support-for-centres/placing-students-in-the-right-exam/)
- [Grammar/Vocab test](https://www.examenglish.com/leveltest/index.html)
- [Listening test](https://www.examenglish.com/leveltest/listening_level_test.htm)
- [TrackTest (requires registration)](https://app.tracktest.eu/en/index.php?page=registration&dir=login)
- [ILS English](http://www.ilsenglish.com/quicklinks/test-your-english-level)
- [EnglishTag](http://www.englishtag.com/tests/level_test.asp)
- [Europa School (60 questions)](https://www.europa-school.co.uk/language-level-test.html)
- [EF Set (15 minutes)](https://www.efset.org/quick-english-check/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another: [DIALANG](http://dialangweb.lancaster.ac.uk).

This one allows you to get a level in Listening, Writing, Reading, Structures (grammar) and Vocabulary. Each test has 30 questions, the listening part takes about 20-30 minutes (perhaps depending on the level), but you should be able to finish the other parts in 10-15 minutes each.

Note: In my opinion, the level it indicates is often quite high.